# A few lines in my image save function don't run after the first time the image is saved

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm making an app that allows you to have a textview over an image, then save that as a brand new image. I'm having a problem keeping the new extended area above the image white to simulate the textview.

Here's what the basis of the app is:

[image: app basis]

Heres what it looks like after I save it the first time:

[image: looks first time]

and heres what it looks like after i save it more than once while the app is open:

[image: while app is open]

(ignore the white border that's from screenshotting the simulator)

This is my save function, it extends the saved image the same amount as the textview (if its actively showing) then it colors the extended area white. it then super imposes the textview text over the white. For some reason it will only color in the extended area white on the first time the image is saved. after that the backgroundColor.setFill() doesn't activate as seen in the screen shots above:

```
 @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    guard image != nil else { return }

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let normalSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.bounds.size.height)
    let textViewWithImageSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: ((screenHeight * 0.17) + scrollView.bounds.size.height))
    var yPos: Int = Int(-offset.y)

    //if textView is active or not and the different y position for saved image to include the textview if it is active
    // screenHeight * 0.17 is the dynamic height of the textview per device.

    if textView.isHidden == true {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(normalSize, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
        textView.text = ""
        yPos = Int(-offset.y)
    }else if textView.isHidden == false {
        yPos = Int(-offset.y + (screenHeight * 0.17))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textViewWithImageSize, true, UIScreen.main.scale)

        //sets saves text area background to white, extendind the image area on its own colored the void black.
        let backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
        backgroundColor.setFill()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: (offset.y - (screenHeight * 0.17)), width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.bounds.size.height))
    }

    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: -offset.x, y: CGFloat(yPos))
    scrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let textColor = UIColor.red
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)!
    let textFontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: textFont,NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor] as [String : Any]
    let rect = CGRect(x: offset.x + 5, y: (offset.y + 5 - (screenHeight * 0.17)), width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.bounds.size.height)

    textView.text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
    centerScrollViewContents()

 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved", message: "your image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Neat", style: .default, handler: nil))
}
```

above is my entire save and render image function, and below is the simple case switch I use to switch whether the textview is present or not:

```
   @IBAction func frame(_ sender: Any) {
     guard image != nil else { return }


    switch currentFrame{
    case 0:
        textView.isHidden = true
    case 1:
        textView.isHidden = false
    default:
        break
    }
    currentFrame += 1
    if currentFrame > 1 {
        currentFrame = 0
    }
}
```

I imagined setting the if statements up in the save function based on whether the textview is hidden or not would be the cleanest solution, which actually seems to be working. but the

```
backgroundColor.setFill()
```

Is being bypassed for some reason after the initial save, but the image still extends and super imposes the text correctly.

Im at a loss and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. This line:

```
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: (offset.y - (screenHeight * 0.17)), width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.bounds.size.height))
```

The y: needed to be

```
y: 0 - (screenHeight * 0.17))
```

instead of trying to match the scrollview image offset like I was trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you were able to solve the problem!